# Free Bootstrap Template doesn't change display in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying several of the free templates at [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/). I download the bootstrap.min.css and put it in my Content directory. My Site.Master file has this in the head section:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
```

I have also the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The display of the page and navbar does not change to be the color and style of the downloaded theme. It stays the same as the one that comes stock with the ASP.NET project templates. Why is this happening? This should be a simple file replace.

Comment: Try to change your stylesheet src to `<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Take a look in the developer tools to see if stylesheet is being loaded.

Comment: It was IE 10 in Windows 8.1! If I do it in Chrome, it works!

Comment: Another solution would be adding `runat=server` and changing path to `~/Content/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: That doesn't change it but there is a line in there <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" /> which renders bootstrap.css, bootstrap.nin.css, and Site.cs

Comment: Use only `bootstrap.css` as it will be minified anyway (assuming you are using bundling from the code you have posted). Also try to edit `web.config` for forcing bundles being re-build.

Comment: It still isn't working in IE 11 but works in Chrome and Firefox. I have only bootstrap.css. How do you edit web.config for forcing bundles being rebuilt?